# scheduleTrigger is not working in 1.8.3.0

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

i am using CruiseControl.NET 1.8.3.0.but scheduleTrigger is not firing. i want  my build should be created every day on 2 o'clock .

```
<triggers>
<scheduleTrigger time="02:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
</triggers>
```

pls let me know how to resolved it asap.

Answer (score 1):

That's 2 am.  CruiseControl.NET uses a 24 hour clock.  So if you wanted to run the build every day at 2 pm, use `14:00` as the time.

```
<triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="02:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
</triggers>
```

Also, have you loaded your ccnet.config file in CCValidator?  It has a good GUI for browsing the configuration file's object model.  This may help you track down where your configuration isn't working.